Recycled brine flow rate
How to find the water flow rate coming out of a pump?  The flow rate entering the pump is 471 t/h. The pump's pressure is 3.6 bar.

is there a similar question where we determine the flow out of a pipe after only knowing the flow rate into it?

Since the pump does not consume the brine nor create more, the flow rate in is always equal to the flow rate out, 471 tonnes/hour. The outlet pressure is immaterial.
What you might be more interested in is the horsepower consumed by the pump. This is equal to the mass flow rate through the pump multiplied by the pressure difference across the pump. Mind the units for pressure and mass flow rate, and remember the conversion factor to get to horsepower.
